# CSS overwrite settings do not work in Angular 15

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular. I'm working on an Angular 15 project that utilizes the Material library. The issue I face is that none of the CSS overrides seem to take effect in my project. For instance, I'm trying to increase the spacing between `mat-table` rows, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032941/increase-gap-between-mat-rows-in-mat-table-angular), using the following code:

```
.mat-table {
    border-collapse: separate!important;
    border-spacing: 0 4px!important;
}
```

or any other global CSS changes do not work on my project,

my **style.css** is:

```
HTML, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }
body { font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you include your style.css in your Typescript class?

Comment: And also, if you have view encapsulation enabled (which is enabled by default), you can't easily override third-party component styles in component-specific stylesheets. You'll need to either put that override style in a global stylesheet, or use `:host ::ng-deep` (which is deprecated technically). Styles in component stylesheets are partially rewritten so that they're scoped to the particular component (your component).

Comment: the canonical way to do this is with *density* via a defined theme: see https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme

Comment: @MustafaYousef i have app.component.ts as my main component and there `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']`  has been included as a style file, should I add style.css in styleUrls as well?

Comment: @Carcigenicate i do not know anything about enabling or disabling encapsulation, but I applied those overwritten in style.css which is a global style, I tried adding CSS overwritten in a related style file of the component that did not work either, I tried using `:host ::ng-deep .mat-table {}` not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest material versions mdc components are being used. Instead of 'mat-table' you can try mat-mdc-table. This might work.

Comment: Hi @Midhun P J, how to know which css selectors like .mat- needs to be replaced with which .mat-mdc- based after MDC migration in the process of upgrading to Angular v15? Because MDC migration has left so many TODO comments in my project and its driving me crazy, as what should i do, no clear cut document to refer to. And blindly replacing all .mat- to .mat-mdc- are resulting in even more new issues